# TypeScript Angular 2 Responses Subscribing

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm trying to return information from my api but I don't understand how to correctly use subscribe. With an array I return an empty array from my service and push values into it as I get them.

How would I correctly return just a single value variable in app-component ts. Right now If I do a `alert(JSON.stringify(authenticated))` it just gives me `{"_isUnsubscribed":false,"_subscriptions":[{"isUnsubscribed":false}]}`

app-component ts

```
checkAuthentication(){
  var authenticated = this._authService.getAuthenication();
}
```

authentication Service

```
 getAuthenication() {
      return this._http.get('auth.php').subscribe(res => {
        if (res.json().authenticated === true){
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
  }
```

auth.php

```
<?
session_start();
$authenticated = ( isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]) ? true : false );
$post_data = json_encode(array(authenticated => $authenticated));
echo $post_data;
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
return this._http.get('auth.php').subscribe(res => {
```

to

```
return this._http.get('auth.php').map(res => {
```

and call it like

```
this._authService.getAuthenication()
    .subscribe(value => this.authenticated = value);
```

Comment: I'm getting Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription<Response>'. Is subscribe for angular or javascript, is there any documentation for it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot a change

Comment: What does authenticated refer to in .subscribe(value => this.authenticated = authenticated); Is that at a variable I have on app.component or is that a property of value? I'm returning true or false in the .map(res should I just be returning the res.json()

Comment: Sorry, again. Should be `value` :-/

Comment: Works great! Btw, is there standard documentation online about map and subscribe, I'm finding mostly blog articles

Comment: I don't know what docs apply most docs about Rx and especially Rxjs I guess. I use only Dart. Rxjs is similar to streams in Dart and I saw how it was used on several questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: You should be getting a double upvotes from everyone.  Thanks for pointing this out.